# How do I deal with a page loading in a secondary browser tab when I run Protractor tests headless (Chrome)?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, protractor, automated-tests, headless

When this code clicks a “Print”-icon, a PDF-file will be generated and displayed in a new browser-tab. I want to switch to this tab, wait until the PDF has finished loading there, check a part of the URL and then close that secondary tab.

```
it( "should open document as PDF-file in new browser-tab", async () => {
    const mUrl = "TherapyReportForm/Export";

    await mTherapyReportView.btnPrintform.click();
    await browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(async (handles) => {
        //if there is a secondary browser-tab open...
        if (handles.length > 1) {
            //...click on it
            await browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[1]);
        }
    });

    //confirm that the url of the secondary tab matches the print-url pattern
    await browser.sleep( 18000 );
    expect( await browser.getCurrentUrl() ).toContain( mUrl );

    await browser.getAllWindowHandles().then( async (handles) => {
        //if there are multiple browser-tabs open
        if (handles.length > 1) {
            //close the secondary and move back to first
            await browser.driver.close();
            await browser.driver.switchTo().window( handles[0] );
        }
    } );
} );
```

The test above works reliably, unless I run it in chromes headless-mode, then the test-run breaks at line

```
expect(await browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain(mUrl);
```

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRg1B.png)

The console output proves that it switches to the secondary tab, but apparently never tries to load the url. Since it fails to close this secondary tab the entire suite will break at that point.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a thing... downloading functionality is not available in headless chrome. That's for sure. What I'm going to talk about below, I'm a little bit uncertain if that's the case

There is no such thing as 'open' pdf file in browser. The reason is that behind scene the browser actually downloads it (maybe temporarily). This is why you'll never be able to do that in headless

But that's rather a shot in the dark

Comment: try to google more info based on the assumption that what I said is true